# Is the pipe overloaded?

Tags: shell-script, solaris, ksh, fifo

I am using a coprocess to run commands in siebel server manager. I am reading commands from a text file (around 2000 commands) and executing them one by one in siebel server manager. After executing around 600 commands, the shell script(ksh in solaris) hangs. And I don't think the root cause is on the siebel server side. So i suspect there is problem with the pipes or the coprocess that I am using. Below is the code I am using to run the commands.variable `srvr_cmd` contains the string to connect to siebel server manager. and file `srvr_commands.txt` contains the commands.`sleep_less` is a function where in script sleeps for 0.1 seconds.Kindly let me know if there is something wrong in my code or is there any limitations for either pipes or coprocess.

```
$srvr_cmd |&  
srvr_pid=$!  
exec 7>&p  
exec 9<&p  
while read commnd  
do  
    count=\`expr $count + 1\`  
    echo $count  
    print -u7 "$commnd"  
    sleep_less  
echo $commnd  
done < srvr_commands.txt
```

Comment: In that code exceirpt, you're not reading the output of the co-process (on fd 9). Likely that pipe will get full which eventually will block srvr_cmd which will mean it won't read from its input, which means the pipe _to_ the coprocess will get full as well at which point the `print -u7` will block as well.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks for your input. Will it work if i close the output pipe? and is this syntax ( `9<&-` ) correct?

Comment: No, if you close the pipe, then srvr_cmd will die (of a SIGPIPE) the next time it writes on stdout. If you want to discard the output of srvr_cmd, you can redirect to /dev/null, but you also don't need a coprocess, just pipe your loop to srvr_cmd.

Comment: Thank you, I will try redirecting the output to `/dev/null`. And I am using coprocess because i don't want to connect and disconnect to siebel server for each command. So I keep it running in the background and pass the commands to be executed.

Comment: If you pipe the loop to srvr_cmd, as in `while... done < file | srv_cmd`, it won't connect and disconnect. You use a co-process when you want a pipe both _to_ the input of the command and _from_ its output, which is not the case here.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas , tried the above and tested. It worked fine. Thank you very much :)